# Get text of elements but separate with spaces

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm grabbing text data from a webpage and when I use `.text` it has all the elements combined. However, I want to separate some of them with a space.

For example, I have this text:

```
data=['<span class="sub-title title-block"><span class="nowrap">1.2</span><span class="nowrap">TEKNA</span></span>',
'<span class="sub-title title-block"><span class="nowrap">Amr</span><span class="nowrap">V12 5.2</span></span>',
'<span class="sub-title title-block"></span>']
```

When I do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in data:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i, 'lxml')
    for d in soup:
        print(d.text)
```

I get:

```
1.2TEKNA
AmrV12 5.2
```

But I want the expected output:

```
1.2 TEKNA
Amr V12 5.2
```

where I get each `text` separated between each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`get_text(<sep>)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method and define your custom separator as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data=['<span class="sub-title title-block"><span class="nowrap">1.2</span><span class="nowrap">TEKNA</span></span>',
'<span class="sub-title title-block"><span class="nowrap">Amr</span><span class="nowrap">V12 5.2</span></span>',
'<span class="sub-title title-block"></span>']

for i in data:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i, 'lxml')
    for d in soup:
        print(d.get_text(" "))
```

Output:

```
1.2 TEKNA
Amr V12 5.2
```